# How can i forward declare a class argument in python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

When declaring Django models, this problem came across:

```
class Foo(Bar):
    pass

class Bar():
    pass
```

> NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined

**How can i forward declare a class argument in python 3.6.7?**

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to? Just swap the order.

Comment: Note that there is a very specific case where you can use a name that hasn't been defined yet, and that's [in type annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/). But even that requires 3.7+, and a `from __future__ import annotations` import to work even there, and doesn't apply to this case at all. Rearrange your definitions.

Comment: @Peritosh This is a Q/A site. There are a bunch of other programming languages that accept switching the order of the declarations, if you are limited to python you can answer "what comes first, the chicken or the...".

Comment: @Daniel I have a huge number of classes, i have some porpuses to write them in non-declarational orders, in groups, to increase readability. That's why i didn't just swap the order, but i guess i will have to.

Comment: I find this to be one of the more annoying things about python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `NameError`, because python reads classes sequentially. (Sequence of classes matters).

```
class Bar:
    pass

class Foo(Bar): 
    ''' Bar is not "class argument". Bar is Super Class(Parent Class) of Foo. '''
```

No `NameError` anymore.